# MySqli and PHP: Not in statement

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to get data by an mysqli query.
Query looks like:

```
SELECT * FROM pxldr_drawings
             ORDER BY RAND()
             WHERE id NOT IN (1,3,4,2)
             LIMIT 1
```

But i get the following error message

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE id NOT IN (1,3,4,2) LIMIT 1' at line 3
```

I also tried  `NOT IN ('1','3','4','2')` and `NOT IN(1,3,4,2)`, but neither worked.

Thanks, LB

Comment: Your ORDER BY and WHERE clauses are in the wrong order. Swap them round.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`WHERE` clause must be before `ORDER BY` clause.

try this

```
      SELECT * FROM pxldr_drawings
          WHERE id NOT IN (1,3,4,2)
          ORDER BY RAND()
          LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1):

The order of clauses is important, `order by` should come after `where`.

```
SELECT * FROM pxldr_drawings
             WHERE id NOT IN (1,3,4,2)
             ORDER BY RAND()
             LIMIT 1
```

For the proper syntax of where different clauses need to be placed, please refer to "[Select Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html)" documentation.